# tkinter positioning objects: anchor

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to position stuff and found out about the anchor keyword. But nothing seems to work as I want. The tutorials don't explain it well enough and even a code as simple as that does not work. How do I place something for example in the bottom right corner. (I am working with the place method and would appreciate solutions with that method)

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("300x300")

frame = Frame(root, bg="blue", width=50, height=50 )
frame.place(anchor=SE)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `place()` takes in `x` and `y` coordinates as arguments, why are you not passing any?, like `place(x=10,y=20)`

Comment: so far to position stuff I used relx, rely, relwidth and relheight. I tried anchor with different combinations of those arguments but every output seems random so I don't even know what is going on and how to fix it. An example code would be appreciated. I just want to know how to position widgets in frames (or Tk() ) in the cornerns and edges

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`anchor` tells `place` which part of the widget to put at the coordinates within the master. An anchor of "nw" (northwest) tells tkinter to put the northwest (upper-left) corner of the widget at the given coordinates. Likewise, "se" (southeast) puts the lower-right corner at the given coordinates.

Other options are "sw" (southwest) for the lower-left corner, and "ne" (northest) for the upper-right corner.

In the following example, the red frame is placed using `anchor='nw'` and the green frame is placed using `anchor='se'`. In both cases they are placed at position 100,100 within a window that is 200x200 (thus, the coordinate is the center of the window)

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.configure(width=200, height=200, background="black")

f1 = tk.Frame(width=50, height=50, background="red")
f2 = tk.Frame(width=50, height=50, background="green")

f1.place(x=100, y=100, anchor="nw")
f2.place(x=100, y=100, anchor="se")

root.mainloop()
```

[image: screenshot of nw and se anchors]

> How do I place something for example in the bottom right corner.

For that you'll want to use a combination of `anchor` with relative placement. With relative coordinates, a relative x coordinate of zero is the far left edge of the master window, and 1.0 is the far right edge. Likewise, a relative y coordinate of zero is the top edge and 1.0 is the bottom edge. A relative value of .5 represents the center of a widget.

To put something at the bottom right corner you want the relative x and y locations of 1.0 and an anchor of "se" to put the bottom-right part of the widget at that position

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.configure(width=200, height=200, background="black")

f1 = tk.Frame(width=50, height=50, background="white")
f1.place(relx=1.0, rely=1.0, anchor="se")

root.mainloop()
```

[image: screenshot of bottom-right corner placement]

Comment: That is a great explanation! Did not even have to read it all to understand it. Better than any tutorial to be honest. Thanks a lot!